# Subject next doesn´t propagate to another component

Tags: angular, rxjs

I´m trying to create a simple push notification listener that will refresh all notifications whenever the front receives a push notification event.

To do that I have a service that receives the push notification and emits an event in a Subject with the next() method.

```js
import { getMessaging, MessagePayload, onMessage } from "firebase/messaging";

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class NotificationService {

    private notificationSubject = new Subject<MessagePayload>();

    receiveMessage() {
        const messaging = getMessaging();
        onMessage(messaging, (payload: MessagePayload) => {
            console.log("new message received. ", payload);
            this.notificationSubject.next(payload);
        });
    }

    public get notificationObservable$():Observable<MessagePayload>{
      return this.notificationSubject.asObservable();
    }
}
```

In my application main class I have the subscription to listen to this event:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './default-layout.component.html'
})
export class DefaultLayoutComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.notificationService.notificationObservable$
    .pipe(
      tap((notification) => console.log("notification", notification)),
      mergeMap(() => this.notificationService.getAllNotifications()),
      tap((notifications) => console.log("notifications", notifications)))
    .subscribe(notifications => this.data = notifications);
  }
}
```

Each new notification that a send with firebase triggers the notification service and prints the "new message received" in the console, but the component subscription does not print or call the API.
If I create the subscription in the NotificationService constructor with the exact same code it works as expected printing the logs and calling the API.

Why does this subscription does not work when I try to use in another component?

Comment: are you reproviding or recreating this service somewhere else? where's the service injection? where is `receiveMessage` being called

Comment: I have one infraModule that provide the NotificationService and the app.module import this infraModule, the DefaultLayoutComponent is inside the app.module

Comment: don't do that. it's provided in root, don't put it in any other providers

Comment: I removed from the provider's session in the infraModule and worked as expected.. thank you.

Comment: getAllNotifications()) is not in your service??